# WebView won't play any sound

Tags: android, audio, webview

I use the simplest instance of WebView and so far everything required works well, except for playing sounds, both javascript invoked sounds and html5 audio tag do not work through this WebView.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/game.html");
    }
}
```

I can exclude issues with the HTML side, since the sound works fine in regular browsers on both PC and phone.

Tested so far on Android 4.4 and Andoroid 7.0 both have sounds within regular browser but no sound within WebView.

Most common answer is that phones require sound to be initiated with a tap on the screen. That does not explain why regular browsers work fine though, while only WebView seems affected.

Comment: try to add  android:hardwareAccelerated="true" in your manifest under application tag

Comment: @LevonPetrosyan given I am building a game hardware acceleration is a good point, thanks, however it did not solve the issue. Answer by Pavel Poley solved it.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try to add this

```
webSettings.setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false)
```

Comment: does not work for me, however I loadUrl from my remote server which serves a react app (created with create-react-app). I use howler.js and I have an .mp3 file in the /public folder, and the only way it does not work is the same: if I use it from an android webview. (It works on desktop, android browser, ios browser, ios webview). .wav does not work either. However it does work if I serve the sound file from an external endpoint. I don't get it why, it seems to me android webview is broken regarding to audio stuff.

Comment: `if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 17) {
            webSettings.setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
}`

This function added to API bigger than 17, so it doesn't work on API's less than 17 and you should put it in an if condition

Comment: In my case, only SOME sounds didn't work, whereas others did. This solution worked also in this case. Strange... but thank you for the solution.

Comment: @PEZO Im investigating why my webview is not working on Samsung phones, and I saw this error in logcat: D/MediaPlayer: setDataSource IOException happend : java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: http://www.mystic-peanut.com/mystic_sites/paintone/media/tones/xylophone/xc1.mp3 this link works on the browser ok, so I want to ask you what it means to server file from external endpoint?

Comment: @pera I meant that if I set the URL of the resource I want to play with howler.js to something "external" as available on the internet: it works. But if I want to to have a local reference to it "/public/mylocalassets/myfile.wav" then it does not work. I have abandoned this projects, so I won't followup in that, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and searched a lot for playing audios in android WebViews. My audio files are stored in Google drive. I can play audio files stored in external servers other than Google drive easily using WebViews. But when I want to read it from Google drive, it shows the icon in the WebViews but when I play I get an error "The audio cannot be played". Finally I found a solution in the website https://www.labnol.org/internet/google-drive-mp3-embed/2232/ which is astonishing. He advises to change the last part of the url to 'preview'. For example the url will be of the form https://drive.google.com/file/d/1234ab56/view?usp=sharing, change the last part view?usp=sharing to preview. So finally url will be
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1234ab56/preview.
And now load it using the same code to load an embedded youtube video in WebView. Thank you.