# I have made embed site in the Android Studio and the site work

Tags: java, android, android-studio, audio, android-webview

I have made embed site in the Android Studio and the site works correctly but the audio which I embed in site is not working. I am a beginner and I want to get help.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mywebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    WebSettings webSettings= mywebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mywebView.loadUrl("https://sites.google.com/view/nbav12");
    // Line of Code for opening links in app
    mywebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

}

//Code For Back Button
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(mywebView.canGoBack())
    {
        mywebView.goBack();
    }

    else
    {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48542978/webview-wont-play-any-sound

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WebView won't play any sound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48542978/webview-wont-play-any-sound)