# Audio Controls Not Working in Android WebView

Tags: android, html

My Android app utilizes a Web View. Within that Web View, I use the following HTML to display an audio player:

```
<audio controls="" preload="none"><source type="audio/mpeg" src="test.mp3"></audio>
```

This worked up until recently. Now, on some Android devices the play button does not work. That is, the audio player does not play any sound when the play button is pressed.

I have not made any recent changes to the Android App or the HTML page it displays, so I'm quite perplexed about why this issue should suddenly appear.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try it
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48543264/6052427
or

I search about how you can use webview in android I found it maybe it's work for u 
https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/677841/Playing-Audio-on-Android-from-an-HTML-File

Comment: webSettings.setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false) this works fine